# ReadInt(), ReadByte(), ReadString(), etc. in Python?

Tags: python

The functions ReadInt(), ReadByte(), and ReadString() (to name a few) exist in other languages for reading input from streams. I am trying to read from a socket, and I want to use functions like these. Are they tucked away in Python somewhere under a different way or has someone made a library for it?

Also, there are Write*datatype*() counterparts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think [struct.unpack_from](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#struct.unpack_from) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 11):

Python's way is using struct.unpack to read binary data.
I'm very used to the BinaryReader and BinaryWriter in C#, so I made this:

```
from struct import *

class BinaryStream:
    def __init__(self, base_stream):
        self.base_stream = base_stream

    def readByte(self):
        return self.base_stream.read(1)

    def readBytes(self, length):
        return self.base_stream.read(length)

    def readChar(self):
        return self.unpack('b')

    def readUChar(self):
        return self.unpack('B')

    def readBool(self):
        return self.unpack('?')

    def readInt16(self):
        return self.unpack('h', 2)

    def readUInt16(self):
        return self.unpack('H', 2)

    def readInt32(self):
        return self.unpack('i', 4)

    def readUInt32(self):
        return self.unpack('I', 4)

    def readInt64(self):
        return self.unpack('q', 8)

    def readUInt64(self):
        return self.unpack('Q', 8)

    def readFloat(self):
        return self.unpack('f', 4)

    def readDouble(self):
        return self.unpack('d', 8)

    def readString(self):
        length = self.readUInt16()
        return self.unpack(str(length) + 's', length)

    def writeBytes(self, value):
        self.base_stream.write(value)

    def writeChar(self, value):
        self.pack('c', value)

    def writeUChar(self, value):
        self.pack('C', value)

    def writeBool(self, value):
        self.pack('?', value)

    def writeInt16(self, value):
        self.pack('h', value)

    def writeUInt16(self, value):
        self.pack('H', value)

    def writeInt32(self, value):
        self.pack('i', value)

    def writeUInt32(self, value):
        self.pack('I', value)

    def writeInt64(self, value):
        self.pack('q', value)

    def writeUInt64(self, value):
        self.pack('Q', value)

    def writeFloat(self, value):
        self.pack('f', value)

    def writeDouble(self, value):
        self.pack('d', value)

    def writeString(self, value):
        length = len(value)
        self.writeUInt16(length)
        self.pack(str(length) + 's', value)

    def pack(self, fmt, data):
        return self.writeBytes(pack(fmt, data))

    def unpack(self, fmt, length = 1):
        return unpack(fmt, self.readBytes(length))[0]
```

Once you have a stream, you put it in the BinaryStream constructor and you got a BinaryStream :)

Example:

```
from binary import BinaryStream

f = open("Users", "rb")
stream = BinaryStream(f)
users_count = stream.readUInt64()
for i in range(users_count):
    username = stream.readString()
    password = stream.readString()
```

Comment: Unrelated, but your readString method allowed me to understand what an errant byte in some data I'm unpacking is, which made the task much easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I used the code of Zippoxer and it works well for almost everything, thank you.

However I had some issue with readString(). It was specified in the C# doc that the length is encoded on 7 bytes. Thus I used readUChar instead of readUInt16:

```
def readString(self):
    length = self.readUChar()
    return self.unpack(str(length) + 's', length)
```

and it works now. Maybe it is specific to my problem ? But it may help someone...

Comment: I know this is a very old question and answer, but if anyone else lands here I found this gist that shows how to read and write a 7-bit encoded integer value: https://gist.github.com/delimitry/7c56945c428ec78ebf2a

Answer (score 0):

Note that Python doesn't have readByte, readInt and readString because it doesn't work directly with all those fancy data types.  Files provides strings which you can convert.

Python `<=` 2.6 has String and that's what you get from your input streams -- strings.  The simple `socket.read()` provides this input.  You can use `struct` to convert the stream into a sequence of integers.  What's important is that the pack and unpack conversions may be by byte, word, long, or whatever, but the Python result is integers.

So your input may be bytes, but Python represents this as a string, much of which is unprintable.  Your desire may be an array of individual values, each between 0 and 255, that are the numeric versions of those bytes.  Python represents these as integers.

Python `>=` 3.0 has bytearrays that can be used to process bytes directly.  You'll can convert them to strings, or integers (which include bytes and longs) or whatever.